# How to secure a connection string in memory after loading it from app.config in a Winforms application

Tags: .net, vb.net, connection-string, password-protection, configurationmanager

I have a legacy application that uses a SQL Server authentication connection string to connect to a local or intranet based SQL Server instance. It currently uses the System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager to get the connection string from the app.config file. However, once that connection string is read from the app.config file, its value is loaded into memory and can be exposed using a tool like Process Hacker to view the applications memory. I currently have module with a method that returns the value of the connection string stored in a SecureString object. The connection string value is loaded into memory on the creation of the ConnectionStringSection Object. The app.config connection string xml is encrypted via instructions given from the microsoft documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files

I understand that it is best practice to use Integrated Security, in this case our connection must use SQL Server Authentication. Is there a way eliminate or minimize the exposure of the connection string in the applications memory?

```
Public Function GetConnectionString() As SecureString
    Dim fileMap As ExeConfigurationFileMap = New ExeConfigurationFileMap
    fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\app.config"
    Dim config As Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
    Dim section As ConnectionStringsSection = TryCast(config.GetSection("connectionStrings"), ConnectionStringsSection)

    Dim secureString As New SecureString

    For Each character As Char In section.ConnectionStrings("ConString").ConnectionString.ToCharArray
        secureString.AppendChar(character)
    Next

    Return secureString
End Function
```

[memory dump after first call to get connection string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQOcD.png)

Comment: Which tool you are using for memory analyze ?

Comment: Look into the `Persist Security Info` key in the connection string.  Not sure but it may be able to help you.

Comment: @dotnetstep processhacker.sourceforge.io run it, find your process -> properties -> memory tab -> strings button and your connection string data stored in program memory after the ConnectionStringsSection object is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the workflow I used to keep the password out of memory in plain text.

1) Encrypt the password in the connection string itself using symmetric encryption so when it is loaded into memory via the call

```
Dim section As ConnectionStringsSection = TryCast(config.GetSection("connectionStrings"), ConnectionStringsSection)
```

the value that is exposed is the encrypted value and not plain text.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/encrypting-data

2) decrypt the password and append it one character at a time to a SecureString object for storage.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=netframework-4.8

```
Public Shared Function DecryptString(ByVal srcString As String) As SecureString

        Dim p As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(srcString)
        Dim rv As RijndaelManaged = New RijndaelManaged
        Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(p)
        Dim cs As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(ms, rv.CreateDecryptor(keyb, ivb), CryptoStreamMode.Read)
        Dim secureString As New SecureString
        Try
            Do
                Dim character As Integer = cs.ReadByte()
                If character = -1 Then
                    Exit Do
                End If
                secureString.AppendChar(Chr(character))
            Loop
        Finally
            ms.Close()
            ms.Dispose()
            cs.Close()
            cs.Dispose()
        End Try
        secureString.MakeReadOnly()
        Return secureString
    End Function
```

3) Use the SecureString object and username to construct a SqlCredential object where "GetUserName()" gets the username out of the connection string, and "GetPassword()" gets the SecureString password

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcredential.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8

```
Dim SqlCredential = New SqlCredential(GetUserName(), GetPassword())
```

4) From here you can construct a SQLConnection object using a connection string that only contains the "Initial Catalog=;Data Source=;" part of the connection string and the SQLCredential object. "GetConnectionString()" would return the aforementioned connection string.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlConnection__ctor_System_String_System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCredential_

```
Dim connection = New SqlConnection(GetConnectionString(), SqlCredential)
```

5) If you are using Entity Framework and need to pass that connection to your DBContext object you can use this constructor.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/connection-management

```
Dim myDbContext = New DBContext(New SqlConnection(ConnectionString, SqlCredential))
```